# real time javascript calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

visit the link to see where the code is. The problem that I'm having is the bottom three groups of checkboxes don't do the right calculations and don't change when not clicked.

https://jsfiddle.net/hunterlop122/nLz0t11u/3/

```
$('input[name=food]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      gettotal();
    }
    else{
    }
});
```

//checks to see if the checkbox's with the name food have been check and which one was checked and then calls the function get total.

Comment: Do I understand it right: You want it to be 10$ when the checkbox is checked and 0$ when not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$(".your-input").on("input", function(){ // });
```

That will change in live, not only on the unfocus event.

Comment: Thanks I will try it out.

Comment: Don't forget to check my answer as "Answered" (the checkmark to the left) if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the response I apologize for not getting back to you sooner thanks for the help , I found a link that helped me for my particular use  here's a link if you want to check it out. www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-calculator-script.phtml